# Google Firestore how to query multiple sub-collections in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore in my project - for each user I have document and in each document I have subcollections (recent, planned).

- items

  - document (uid)

    - sub-collection (recent)

      - doc1 (several fields)
      - doc2 ...
    - sub-collection (planned)

      - doc1 ...
      - doc2 ...

Currently, I am using two StreamBuilders in my app - one for `getRecent` getter and second for `getPlanned`, but I think, that this is not a good approach.

Is out there any better way, how to query these two sub collections (in the future, there will be more..) in one stream? (Or how to optimize my program to not use much bandwidth)

Here is example of my code in Flutter

```
  // Get planned (getter in Data service class)
  Stream<dynamic> get getPlanned {
    return data
        .document(uid)
        .collection("planned")
        .snapshots()
        .map(_snapshotToPlanned);
  }

  // Stream Builder in Home widget
  StreamBuilder(
    stream: Data(uid: user.uid).getPlanned,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
          plannedTrips = snapshot.data;

          if (snapshot.data.length == 0) return NothingWidget();

          return PageView.builder(
            pageSnapping: true,
            controller: _pageController,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: plannedTrips.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return PlannedTrip(planned: plannedTrips[i]);
            },
          );
        } else ...
```

Do you have any idea, how to deal with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: If they are basically the same, why create two sub collections instead of differentiating between planned and recent with one field inside document say type = planned or recent?

Comment: Well, they are basically same, except that one have more fields than other.

Comment: Doesn't matter if one has more field than other this is not like RDBMS so stick to same collection

Comment: But how should I do that on the UI? I have separate section for "recent" and "planned". Should I use two stream builders and inside each check if object has some special property? Or is there better solution?